With git, how to minimize pain when switching between branches with differing .gitignores?
I am in a position where I switch branches in a single repo regularly, working on my own projects, and reviewing collaborator’s code by running it. Often new code will generate intermediary files that shouldn’t be tracked by git. A collaborator will have added these files to the .gitignore on their branch, to be reviewed as part of a pull request.
When switching between branches, files that were ignored on one branch will appear as ‘untracked files’ on another branch, after running git status. It is confusing and distracting to figure out what the deal is with these files

Did I accidentally generate these files on my current branch?
Was I supposed to add these files on my branch, and I forgot?

As I’m switching back and forth, it’s even possible that these files are from a branch more than one branch switch ago.
Sometimes (this has happened multiple times!) these untracked files get accidentally added and committed by other developers on an unrelated branch and then merged to the main branch. This leads to annoying time-sink decluttering efforts later.
What’s the best workflow to minimize pain?
One solution could be run git clean -fd after each branch switch, either manually or in a post-checkout hook. However, this stomps over other workflows.
A workaround I’ve used in the past is to have multiple clones of the repo checked out, just like git-worktree, but this is cumbersome for its own reasons. This is especially true if the size of the git repo is large.
What I think I want is:
When the command git checkout <branch a> is run, and the .gitignore on <branch a> differs from the current HEAD, delete any files in the repo matching the pattern in HEAD’s .gitignore but not <branch a>’s. I feel like this may have undesired side effects, however.
A potentially safer option, a post-checkout warning:
$ git checkout <branch a>
Switched to branch ‘<branch a>’
Warning: the following files are no longer ignored: <truncated list...>


I reckon that best practice is to have one .gitignore file per project.

@TimBiegeleisen this is fine, but while these projects are on separate branches not yet merged to the main branch, people will still run into this problem when switching branches. Know what I mean?

"What’s the best workflow to minimize pain?" - Open the PRs/branches in a web-based UI and manually copy their .gitignore files' changes into your workspace's own .gitignore and  commit to your main/master - after that then rebase the branches onto your main.

"A workaround I’ve used in the past is to have multiple clones of the repo checked out, just like git-worktree, but this is cumbersome for its own reasons. This is especially true if the size of the git repo is large." <-- This sounds like the best idea overall, actually. Though do you need to have the entire worktree deployed instead of a subset thereof?

If it is relevant to add the ignored files, update the .gitignore in both branches (with one commit on each branch)

Whatever you do, do not run git clean -fd automatically in a post-checkout hook.
I could see this happening: You're working on a new test case for several hours. Test case is implemented in a new source code file, which you have not yet committed. All of a sudden, for some reason, you need to check something on another branch. You checkout the other branch, and oops, your test case implementation is gone from the clean. I have lost a full day's work by careless use of git clean before. It feels pretty bad...
